# What are Rising Words™ and Falling Words™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

This puzzle is inspired by the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)

---

If a word conforms to a specific rule, I call it a **rising** word. If it conforms to a different rule, I call it a **falling** word. Here is a list of examples:

| RISING | FALLING | NEITHER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yellow | green | black |
| oil | vinegar | water |
| small | large | more |
| good | evil | intermediate |
| ten | two | twelve |
| come | go | protect |
| peach | tree | fruit |
| river | ground | sky |
| flat | rice | wine |

Here's a CSV:

```
RISING, FALLING, NEITHER
yellow, green, black
oil, vinegar, water
small, large, more
good, evil, intermediate
ten, two, twelve
come, go, protect
peach, tree, fruit
river, ground, sky
flat, rice, wine
```

Notes:

As usual, the associations through rows have nothing to do with the rules; that is, a word being in a group is independent of other words in other groups. (Forgive my failed attempts at making some of the row patterns coherent)

Hints:

> The two rules are related to each other.

> Don't overthink it.

Bonus puzzle: Find a word which is both rising and falling. (I myself am actually not aware of any, but there almost definitely should be at least one based on my knowledge.)

Comment: Don't overthink it. Welp, too late. Haha

Comment: Balancing puzzles from the writer's point of view is surprisingly hard, I guess. In hindsight, knowledge tag makes things very difficult from the massive search space

Comment: I think i've crossed off Fpenooyr naq gur crevbqvp gnoyr, so that is something

Comment: Jnvg, ubj jbhyq lbh rira rkgenpg crevbqvp gnoyr qngn sebz gurfr jbeqf? V'z vagrerfgrq (:

Comment: I was thinking maybe you could spell the words with the symbols-- some fwd, some bkwrds, and some not at all. Nope.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the rules are:

> **Rising**: The word, when translated to Mandarin, results in a word with a rising tone (2nd tone of rising or 3rd tone of falling then rising)
>  **Falling**: Ditto, but results in a falling tone (4th tone)
>  **Neither**: Ditto, but results in a flat tone (1st tone), no tone (aka 5th tone), or multiple tones/words
>
>  This requires an understanding of the [four tones](https://www.learn-chinese.com/mandarin-chinese-tones-pinyin/) used in Mandarin pronunciation.  I will list the translated words using Pinyin which uses diacritics to denote the tones.
>
>  Examples: flat = mā, rising = yú, falling-rising = wǒ, falling = bù

The rules applied:

> Yellow, Green, Black
>  Huáng, Lǜ, Hēi
>
>  Oil, Vinegar, Water
>  Yóu, Cù, Shuǐ (water should be considered rising?)
>
>  Small, Large, More
>  Xiǎo, Dà, Duō
>
>  Good, Evil, Intermediate
>  Hǎo, Huài, Zhōng
>
>  Ten, Two, Twelve
>  Shí, Èr, Shí'èr
>
>  Come, Go, Protect
>  Lái, Qù, Bǎohù
>
>  Peach, Tree, Fruit
>  Táo, Shù, Shuǐguǒ
>
>  River, Ground, Sky
>  Hé, Dì, Tiān
>
>  Flat, Rice, Wine
>  Píng, Fàn, Pútáojiǔ
>
>  Note that there may be multiple ways to translate these words, and in particular, "water" doesn't fit the rules so I may be missing something.
>
>  I mostly used a translation app, so maybe a native speaker could double check the translations and pronunciations to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Indeed, “wine” can be one word too.

Comment: I think you might be onto something.  Curious to see the op's reply.

Comment: @jlee I don't think the author is active any more, so we may never know.  It's too much of a coincidence for 26 of the words to work out that way.  I just wish I knew whether "water" was a mistake or whether there was something else (a dialect, different translation, etc)?  If not for that one word, I would be 100% confident of the answer.

Comment: Yes, way too many coincidences. +1 -- I don't know Mandarin, but I found [this](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/chinese-word-d2dddf0d4414b747bcd29309343f35293a9b1df2.html).   Would Shuǐsè be considered neither rising nor falling? I notice that Bǎohù has similar diacritical marks and it is "neither". Apparently aqua is another word for water, although I don't think I have heard it used interchangeably.

Comment: @jlee Those words "shuǐsè" refer to a color (shuǐ meaning water and sè meaning color = aqua/water color).  Most of the words translated to a single Mandarin word/syllable, although different translations could be made.  For example, yellow = Huáng, but you could also translate it to Huángsè (i.e. yellow color).  I chose the simplest one-word/syllable translations for the most part.  I don't think there is a one-word/syllable translation for "Protect" or "Fruit".  However, "wine" could be just "jiǔ" (generic alcoholic drink) as opposed to "Pútáojiǔ" (grape alcoholic drink).

Comment: Are you sure the op is inactive? They might very well be back. It says last active over a month ago, but you never know - might sign back on tomorrow. I went 7 years between sign ins one time.